# How can I use really big creatures against low-level PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, monsters, creature-size

I want the PCs to fight giant, humongous, colossal, really big creatures during a quest, but the PCs are only level 1 through 3. How can a DM pit low-level PCs against such creatures without the PCs gaining too much XP too quickly?

Comment: Thanks for the help with posting. This is my first time on the forum and I'm just figuring out how it works.

Comment: Next question: are you concerned with the physical size of the enemies, them being metaphorically "big" as in having a high CR (I.e. lots of damage and high HP), or both? What's your goal here?

Comment: I really only went in to change the tags, but the character/player divide is a source of constant amusement, so I cleaned that up, too. Feel free to edit the question further to make it more your own and express your concerns. Your questions remain yours no matter who edits them.

Comment: Having your PC's fight the large creatures is hardly a problem -- just set up the encounter -- the question is how important is it to you that they win, or have a decent chance at victory?

Comment: I am concerned with having them be physically big and very strong. I am hoping to build in some sort of method that the players will need to discover to kill the enemy. Looking at the Monster Manual for 5e, it seems many of this enemy creatures have very high CRs. Let's say a level 1 fighter gets access to a catapult and hits a stone giant and kills it. Does the player get all that experience?

Comment: @Blink That is a separate question directly related to how to award XP, which is covered in the DMG and has some Q&A's here; search for [dnd-5e] and experience in the search bar and see what people have answered, you may not need to ask a separate question.

Comment: Twice you've asked about XP. I think maybe we've misunderstood your question. You've mentioned that you're already planning to give a “weak spot” to make defeat possible and more puzzle-like, so I think the title might be misleading us. Is your problem really only about **how XP works if they defeat a very powerful, giant creature**, or perhaps **how to avoid giving too much XP for defeating such a creature**?

Comment: Why is this question on hold? I just read the question and believe the question is rather obvious. Perhaps it has been edited already but I think it is fairly clear.

Comment: @Mouhgouda This is the answer I was looking for. I guess I have a bunch of questions now that you have all helped me narrow my focus. I have only ever played as a player and not a GM, so I am trying to figure out what others do to append to my quests.

Comment: @Mouhgouda **Don't answer in comments.** Now there is far less motive to ever clarify the question, the question might never be reopened, and nobody else will ever benefit from it (which is the goal of this site's existence). This is why we have that rule.

Comment: @Blink In the interest of this question being fixed, please clarify what you are asking, so that this can be reopened properly and Mouhgouda and/or others can post answers in the *answer* section, where peer review and quality controls can be used. (Comments aren't/can't be peer reviewed or quality-controlled because they are not supposed to contain answers, only be used to help fix questions.)

Comment: @Blink You may get a flatly *better* answer that can go into more detail than what Mouhgouda provided if the question gets reopened. Comments don't tend to have much room for useful information, nor much capacity for pointing out when someone has made grievous errors.

Comment: @doppelgreener How do I get the question reopened?

Comment: @Blink There's some requests in comments here asking for your question to be clarified. You've answered some, but I think [this critical one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89995/?noredirect=1#comment205361_89995) from SSD still needs some answering so we get what you're after. Mouhgouda provided a response which was in line with what you were after -- what were you after? Ultimately the question gets reopened when five site citizens have cast reopen votes; they'll tend to do that when the question's in a good clear state. Clarifying your question will get it there.

Comment: @Mouhgouda If you want to argue with basic site functions, use [meta] instead of ranting in comments. Also, notice that no moderator's name is on the close reason.